# SUM sqlite column double values in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I must get the sum of the values of a column, but I get the number of the rows of the table.

Here is the code that I use to retrieve the sum value:

```
Cursor c=sqLite.getPrezzoTotaleCarrello();

        while(c.moveToNext())
        {
            prezzoTotaleCarrello.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Somma_totale"))); 
            Log.d(prezzoTotaleCarrello.getText().toString(),"Visualizziamo");
        }
```

Here is the code of the getPrezzoTotaleCarrello() method:

```
public Cursor getPrezzoTotaleCarrello()
    {
        String query = "select SUM(Prezzo_totale) AS Somma_totale  from Carrello";

        return getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(query, null);
    }
```

The method getPrezzoTotaleCarrello is inside a class extending SQLiteOpenHelper.

Prezzo_totale is a column that contains double values.
It's incredible I've tried the same code with a column containing integer values and it works.
I don't understand why it happens.

I had to use cursor.getDouble() instead of cursor.getString().
Now there is another problem the part after the dot is cut. For example if the value is 2.55 I see in the TextView 2.00.

Here is the new code:

```
Cursor c=sqLite.getPrezzoTotaleCarrello();

        while(c.moveToNext())
        {
            prezzoTotaleCarrello.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f",c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("Somma_totale")))));
            Log.d(prezzoTotaleCarrello.getText().toString(),"Visualizziamo");
        }
```

New code:

```
while(c.moveToNext())
        {
           // prezzoTotaleCarrello.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f",c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("Somma_totale")))));

            Double total = c.getDouble(0);
            prezzoTotaleCarrello.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f",total)));

            Log.d(prezzoTotaleCarrello.getText().toString(),"Visualizziamo");
        }
```

Here is all the code:

```
class custom_list_one extends BaseAdapter
{
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    ViewHolder holder;
    private ArrayList<Prodotti> cartList=new ArrayList<Prodotti>();
    int cartCounter;
    Typeface type;
    Context context;
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ITALY);

    public custom_list_one(Context context, ArrayList<Prodotti> cart_list) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.cartList=cart_list;
        this.cartCounter= cartList.size();
        this.context = context;
        //type= Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/book.TTF");
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return cartCounter;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {

        return cartList.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {

        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Prodotti tempProdotti = cart_list.get(position);

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listone_custom, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.nome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            holder.quantita_scelta= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantita_scelta_carrello);
            holder.cancel = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
            holder.prezzo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prezzo);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

        holder.nome.setText(tempProdotti.getNome());
        holder.nome.setTypeface(type);

        holder.quantita_scelta.setText(tempProdotti.getQuantita());
        holder.quantita_scelta.setTypeface(type);


        holder.prezzo.setText(tempProdotti.getPrezzo());
        holder.prezzo.setTypeface(type);




            //otteniamo la somma di tutti i prezzi dei prodotti del carrello

        Double somma=sqLite.getPrezzoTotaleCarrello();
        Log.d(String.valueOf(somma),"Visualizziamoooooooo");
        String sommaStringa= String.valueOf(somma);
        prezzoTotaleCarrello.setText(String.valueOf(sommaStringa));
           /*
            Cursor c=sqLite.getPrezzoTotaleCarrello();
        while(c.moveToNext())
        {
           // prezzoTotaleCarrello.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f",c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("Somma_totale")))));

            Double total = c.getDouble(0);
            prezzoTotaleCarrello.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f",total)));

            Log.d(prezzoTotaleCarrello.getText().toString(),"Visualizziamo");
        }*/





           // Number number2=format.parse(tempProdotti.getPrezzo());
            //Double prezzoTotaleProdotto=number2.doubleValue();

            //aggiorniamo la casella di testo relativa alla somma totale dei prezzi dei prodotti del carrello
           // prezzoTotaleCarrello.setText( String.valueOf(String.format("%.2f", (prezzoTotale+prezzoTotaleProdotto))));
          /*
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/



        holder.cancel.setOnClickListener(new MyPersonalClickListener("button_delete", tempProdotti));

        return convertView;
    }
    class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView nome;
        TextView prezzo;
        TextView quantita_scelta;
        ImageButton cancel;
    }

}
```

Comment: I just run the same query on BD I have and it worked.

Comment: But I don't get the sum value

Comment: It should be a double value

Comment: Where could be the error?

Comment: As your sql seems to work, you should check your Android code probably the problem is over there.

Comment: Could you try my code summing double values?

Comment: In my table Prezzo_totale is a colum that contains double values

Comment: The code works with a column that contains integer values.

Comment: your using `getString` method instead `getDouble`.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getDouble(int)

Comment: It works but it cuts the part after the dot.

Comment: For example if the value is 2.55 I see in the TextView 2.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it like this :

```
String query = "select SUM(Prezzo_totale) Somma_totale  from Carrello";
```

Your problem is here :

```
Double prezo = cursor.getDouble(0);
```

**Edited :** this is a sample code :

```
String query = "select SUM(Prezzo_totale) AS Somma_totale  from Carrello");
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
if (cursor.getCount()>0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Double total = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("Somma_totale"));
}
```

**Edit 2 :**

```
    //otteniamo la somma di tutti i prezzi dei prodotti del carrello

    //Double somma=sqLite.getPrezzoTotaleCarrello();
    Double somma= (Double)0;
    Cursor cursor = sqLite.getPrezzoTotaleCarrello();
    if (cursor.getCount()>0) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    somma = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("Somma_totale"));
}    

    Log.d(String.valueOf(somma),"Visualizziamoooooooo");
    String sommaStringa= String.valueOf(somma);
    prezzoTotaleCarrello.setText(String.valueOf(sommaStringa));
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75549/discussion-between-ahmad-ebrahimi-and-ptr).